# Record Transaction status commit/rollback

Tags: sql, transactions, sql-server-2016

I have multiple delete statements which will look similar to what I have written below. However,I want to record the row_count for each table deletes and also the status of transaction. 
How do I get if the delete in the transaction completed successfully or not and record that in the Delete_Log_table that I have. Also, what if the delete fail, I will have to stop the deletes from going forward.

Please help :

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

DELETE FROM [DB].[SCHEMA].[EXAMPLE_TABLE]
WHERE MY_ID IN (SELECT MY_ID FROM #TEMP_TABLE)

COMMIT TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO [DELETE_LOG_TABLE] 
(TABLE_NAME, ROW_COUNT_DELETED, STATUS_OF_TRANSACTION, LOAD_DATE)
('EXAMPLE_TABLE',@@ROWCOUNT, 'HOW DO I GET COMMIT/ROLLBACK HERE- HELP', GETDATE())
```

Comment: You need to use TRY and CATCH

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `TRY` and `CATCH` for what you need. Here is your example:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    DELETE FROM [DB].[SCHEMA].[EXAMPLE_TABLE]
    WHERE MY_ID IN (SELECT MY_ID FROM #TEMP_TABLE)

    INSERT INTO [DELETE_LOG_TABLE] 
    (TABLE_NAME, ROW_COUNT_DELETED, STATUS_OF_TRANSACTION, LOAD_DATE)
    ('EXAMPLE_TABLE',@@ROWCOUNT, 'Successful', GETDATE())

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    INSERT INTO [DELETE_LOG_TABLE] 
    (TABLE_NAME, ROW_COUNT_DELETED, STATUS_OF_TRANSACTION, LOAD_DATE)
    ('EXAMPLE_TABLE',0, 'Error. Detail is :'+ERROR_MESSAGE(), GETDATE())


    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```